# Calculate $\mathbb{E}[F(Y)]$

Tags: probability

I try to resolve this problem, but I have some difficulties to get a clear result.

**The problem :**

Let X be a normal random variable with mean 0 and variance 1 (ie. $X\sim \mathcal{N}(0,1)$).

Let Y be a normal random variable with mean $m$ and variance $\sigma^{2}$ (ie. $Y\sim \mathcal{N}(m,\sigma^{2})$).

X and Y are independent random variables.

What I want is to compute $I=\mathbb{E}[\Phi(Y)]$ where $\Phi$ is the the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$.

**What I done is wrong **
Sorry for my english :)

Comment: I might be missing something, but don't quite get why are you considering $X$ as a random variable. $\phi(\cdot)$ is just a function like any other. If you want to compute $E(g(Y))$,that's just $\int g(y) f_Y(y) dy$

Answer (score 6):

As leonbloy says, you just need to use
$$E[\Phi(Y)] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(y)\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mathrm dy.$$
But, rather than trying to evaluate the integral directly, consider that we can
write it as 
$$\begin{align*}
E[\Phi(Y)] &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(y)\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{(y-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X \leq y\}f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty P\{X \leq y \mid Y = y\}f_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy\\
&= P\{X \leq Y\}\\
&= P\{X-Y\leq 0\}.
\end{align*}$$
What kind of random variable is $X-Y$? Can you find its mean and variance
without doing any integrations? Can you write an expression for this probability
in terms of $\Phi(\cdot)$?

Comment: Thanks a lot !  $X-Y\sim \mathbb{N}(-m,1+\sigma^{2})$ because $X$ and $Y$ are independent. Then, $\mathbb{P}(X-Y\le 0) = \Phi\left(\frac{m}{\sqrt{1+\sigma^{2}}}\right)$. Your result is correct because I check it for simples values : If $m=0$ and $\sigma=1$, then, $\Phi(Y)\sim \mathcal{U}(0,1)$, $\mathbb{E}[\Phi(Y)]=\Phi(0)$.